# Simple Unwrap all messed up

Tags: mesh, uv

here's my problem.
I've just started using Blender and I've almost finished to model my kitchen for my project. I'm trying to unwrap the sink faucet, but I have some problems even with quite simple shapes.
the island in the pic is a cylinder which has 4 circular cuts made with a boolean modifier. As you can see, the mesh is all messed up.
I can't really tell what make that non to unwrap properly. any advice?[image]

Comment: Your mesh has [bad topology](http://topologyguides.com). Never use booleans folks

Comment: Move your seem over a couple faces so you have clean quads on both sides of the seam. Select just two quads on either side of the seam and unwrap those. Use select-linked to separate and scale so they're in aporoximatly the right place and pin their vertices. Then select everything in 3d and unwrap again. If you turn on "live unwrap transform" you can move the pinned pieces around and the unpinned will recalculate.

Comment: Booleans are not evil. But requires nearly always some work afterwards.  On topic, triangulate the mesh, then make tris to quads. And then the unwrap should work.